# How to handle variable length data for LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

From what I know the general steps to preprocess data for LSTM include the following steps

```py
vocab_size = 20000  # Only consider the top 20k words
maxlen = 200  # Only consider the first 200 words of each movie review
(x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val) = keras.datasets.imdb.load_data(num_words=vocab_size)
print(len(x_train), "Training sequences")
print(len(x_val), "Validation sequences")
x_train0 = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_val0 = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(x_val, maxlen=maxlen)
```

Here, train will consist of 25,000 samples of variable length, and after applying the sequence padding it will truncate data to be of length 200 if the sequence is more than 200 in length & will pad 0's to the data for cases where data is shorter than 200 in length.

But this isn't a big problem if your data is sequence of length 200 +/- 50 or has a range from 90 to 500.

**How do you tackle a problem where data length's range from 100 -> 60,000 length?**

Comment: It's very unlikely that the length of your data will vary that much. And as far as I know, there is no convention about how to find the perfect sequence length. Maybe some trial-and-error would help here.

Comment: Find out the percentage of data samples with each length. Most likely there are outliers in your data.

Comment: JosmyFaure, Aniket Bote  thank for the advice I think you are right data should not be spread so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a way to handle that in LSTM architecture: **

1. In you lstm set the timestep component of input_shape argument as
   None, this will help you accept sequence of variable length.
2. Now one problem will raise because you will have to fit the inputs
   into numpy array, which has a strict structure (same length). So
   what I do is **Group you inputs into batches of same length** and
   make an array of it. Now feed it to your network.

Ex-

```
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(latent_dim, input_shape=(None, vocab_len, ))

for ip in inputs.groupby(lenghtofinputs):
    model.fit(ip, outputof(ip), epoch=100)
```

Please let me know if it's working with your case, works for me.

Comment: I think this is the best option I have come across so far. Here is a rough sketch of my implementation, (it's a very rough version still needs a lot of work) https://gist.github.com/SpinachXPasta/277d0661fd5ab5aa6aff8f386c6a5fdf

Comment: Exactly, what I am talking about. Are you working on text summarisation problem?

Comment: Its actually sequence classification, I am trying out various approaches, LSTM would have been the best approach, but the variable lengths was getting in the way